# Elasticsearch custom sorting / adding filter clauses scores

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have this simple documents set:

```
{
  id : 1,
  book_ids : [2,3],
  collection_ids : ['a','b']
},
{
  id : 2,
  book_ids : [1,2]
}
```

If I run this ***filter query***, it will match both documents:

```
{
    bool: {
        filter: [
            {
                bool: {
                    should: [
                        {
                            bool: {
                                must_not: {
                                    exists: {
                                        field: 'book_ids'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            bool: {
                                filter: {
                                    term: {
                                        book_ids: 2
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                bool: {
                    should: [
                        {
                            bool: {
                                must_not: {
                                    exists: {
                                        field: 'collection_ids'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            bool: {
                                filter: {
                                    term: {
                                        collection_ids: 'a'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The thing is I want to sort these documents, and I would like the first one (id: 1) to be returned first because it matched both the `book_ids` value and the `collection_ids` values provided.

A simple ***sort*** clause like this one is not working:

```
[
  'book_ids',
  'collection_ids'
]
```

because it will return first document 2 due to the `book_ids` array first value.

*Edit*: this is a simplified example of the problem I am facing, which has N such clauses in the should clause. Moreover there is an order between the clauses, as I tried to reflect with the `sort` snippet: results matching the first clause (`book_ids`) should appear before results matching the second clause (`collection_ids`). I am really looking for some kind of SQL sort operation where I would only take into account the matching value of the field array. A viable option might be to assign decreasing constant_scores to each `term` clause, according to the expected sort order, and ES would have to sum this sub-scores to compute the final score. But I cannot figure out how to do it or if it is even possible.

*Bonus question*:
is there any way for ElasticSearch to return some kind of new document with only the matching values? Here is what I would expect as a response to the above ***filter query***:

```
{
  id : 1,
  book_ids : [2],
  collection_ids : ['a']
},
{
  id : 2,
  book_ids : [2]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're right about the constant score idea. I think you can do it like this:

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          bool: {
            should: [
              {
                bool: {
                  must_not: {
                    exists: {
                      field: 'book_ids'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                constant_score: {
                  filter: {
                    term: {
                      book_ids: 2
                    }
                  },
                  boost: 100
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          bool: {
            should: [
              {
                bool: {
                  must_not: {
                    exists: {
                      field: 'collection_ids'
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                constant_score: {
                  filter: {
                    term: {
                      collection_ids: 'a'
                    }
                  },
                  boost: 50
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }  
  }
}
```

I think the only thing you were missing using constant score, was likely just that the top level query needs to be `must`, not `filter`. (There's no scoring for filters, all the scores are 0.)

An alternative would be to put the filter inside a `function_score` query (but leave it as a filter), and then compute the score as you want (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

As to the bonus question, it's possible if you use a script field to filter and add a new field like you want (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html), but it's not possible in a straightforward way. It's probably easier and makes more sense to do that filtering after you receive the result, unless you have very long lists in your values.

Comment: Hi @dshockley, thanks for taking the time to look at this. To answer you: yes, this behaviour was intended and I think I cannot use this re-writing as I have more than 2 such clauses. I'll clarify this in my question. Moreover there really is a sort order to my problem, results matching the first clause (```book_ids```) should appear before results matching the second clause (```collection_ids```). With the solution you propose, I don't think it is the case. And I really need to generalize to N such clauses.

Comment: Ah I see -- it's much more clear now -- I've edited my answer to show how I think you can do it with constant_score.

Comment: I think it's generalizable to as many terms as you want, but you have to pick the boost scores carefully (and use "explain": true to figure out what's going on if it doesn't behave like you expect)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but couldn't figure out :) Thanks a lot. Your query is not working as is btw: there is a missing ```query``` key just under ```function_score``` at least in ES 5. If you can update it, I will validate the answer. And you are right, I will have to be careful with the scoring but I couldn't find anything better to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm glad it works! :)

Actually I think it doesn't need the function_score at all (sorry, I left it in by mistake after trying a different approach). I edited the answer to remove the function_score entirely.